# Looping over associative array in Perl

Tags: perl

Probably a super simple problem, getting the super helpful error message when trying to loop over a nested associative array:

> Global symbol "%t" requires explicit package name

Code is:

```
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my %test;
$test{"1"}{"stuff"} = "foo";
$test{"2"}{"stuff"} = "bar";
```

Then dumping the second level arrays is fine:

```
foreach my $t (values %test){
        print Dumper($t);
}
```

Which gives:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'stuff' => 'foo'
        };
$VAR1 = {
          'stuff' => 'bar'
        };
```

But as soon as i try accessing the third level strings, i get the above error, no matter what combination of $'s, @'s, %'s, qoutes or brackets i use.

```
foreach my $t (values %test){
        print Dumper($t{"stuff"});
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you get are hash *references*, and as such, you'll have to dereference them:

```
foreach my $t (values %test){
 print Dumper($t->{'stuff'})
}
```

In perl `%t`, `@t` and `$t` (and `&t`, but that's special in most cases) are all different variable names. For element access you use the corresponding paren type to say which variable you mean:

```
$t{boo} # accesses %t
$t[800] # accesses @t
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to do `$t->{"stuff"}`. `$t` is a hash reference (not an actual hash) so you need to use the dereferencing operator.